# Поиск в mysql по маске(шаблону)

Tags: mysql, sql, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите можно ли реализовать запрос по маске.

Например пользователь ищет полный текст либо начинает его "`asdASD123`",
а в таблице есть столбец где задана макса "`asd_S_1__`",
если было бы наоборот то я бы делал через **REGEXP**, а как в данном случае составить запрос

---

у меня в таблице есть строки со значениями в столбце вида:

```
asd_S_1__ Bd_S_1_ a___S_1__ asd_S_1__
```

и нужно что при запросе пользователя `aoooSa1hh` 
выводилась строка со значение в столбце `a___S_1__`

Comment: удалить все лишние символы, оставив только буквы и цифры и привести обе стороны к нижнему регистру........дальше like

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: И `WHERE table.column LIKE user_input`, и `WHERE user_input LIKE table.column` - вполне нормальные выражения отбора.

Comment: Хранить в таблице все возможные маски - это очень неэффективно. Какую собственно задачу вы решаете с помощью таких таблиц?

Comment: У меня есть база с документами где в поле хранятся не полные VIN номера и этот документ надо найти. @Akina способ помог. Только поправил базу вместо знака _ поставил %